# Python отправка почты, не все получателям приходит вложение

Tags: python, python-3.x

Рассылаю почту по спискам адресов с вложением файла. Почему-то, некоторые получатели, получают письмо без вложения.

```
class AWSSender:
    s = smtplib.SMTP()
    s.connect('my.post.server', 25)
    s.login('login', 'pass')

    def quit(self):
        s.quit()

    def send(self, email, me):
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = 'email theme'
        msg['From'] = me
        msg['To'] = email

        body = 'some text'
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body))

        filename = r'\\path\to\file'
        attachment = open(filename, 'rb')

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=file.name")
        msg.attach(part)

        self.s.sendmail(me, email, msg.as_string())
        print("Sent email to " + email, end="")

emaillist = open('list.txt', 'r').readlines()


aws = AWSSender()

for email in emaillist:
    aws.send(email, "noreply@server.name")
```

Comment: Скорее всего антивирус на сервере этих получателей удаляет потенциально опасные вложения.

Comment: Сейчас проверяю, возможна одна из причин строка  aws.send(email, "noreply@server.name") указанный адрес отправки реально не существует.

Comment: Нет, такая же ситуация. Если рассылать через почтовый клиент, все приходит, а через скрипт - вложение не у всех.

Comment: Вы уверены, что почтовый клиент вложению устанавливает такой же тип MIME?

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо -  Sergey Gornostaev.
Помогло изменение mime типа с alternative на mixed